# Async/Await with WebdriverJS and CucumberJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

Im using webdriverJS and cucumberJS to automate an application. All the cucumber steps are defined as async functions and they in turn call functions in page objects with await.

Similarly, all my page object functions are also async. And I have await to invoke all the webdriver operations. Somehow, it starts firing multiple steps at the  same time and my script apparently fails. For example, when I'm on the 3rd page of the application, the script starts looking for a element on 4th page and fails. It doesn't work in the sequence that I expect it to. The strangest thing is, it works fine for the first couple of pages of the application.

I may sound vague without any supporting code. Unfortunately, I'm not able to share the code samples here. Any help would be appreciated.